# how to check input string with list of pattern sequentially in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have specific patterns which composed of string, numbers and special character in specific order. I would like to check input string is in the list of pattern that I created and print error if seeing incorrect input. To do so, I tried of using `regex` but my code is not neat enough. I am wondering if someone help me with this.

**use case**

I have input `att2_epic_app_clm1_sub_valid`, where I split them by `_`; here is list of pattern I am expecting to check and print error if not match.

Rule:

input should start with att and some number like `[att][0-6]*`, or `[ptt][0-6]`; after that it should be continued at either `epic` or `semi`, then it should be continued with `[app][0-6]` or `[app][0-6_][clm][0-9_]+[sub|sup]`; then it should end with `[valid|Invalid]`

so I composed this pattern with `re` but when I passed invalid input, it is not detected and I expect error instead.

```
import re

acceptable_pattern=re.compile(r'([att]+[0-6_])(epic|semi_)([app]+[0-6_]+[clm]+[0-6_])([sub|sup_])([valid|invalid]))'
    input='att1_epic_app2_clm1_sub_valid'   # this is valid string

wlist=input.split('_')
for each in wlist:
  if any(ext in each for ext in acceptable_pattern): 
     print("valid")
  else:
     print("invalid")
```

this is not quite working because I have to check the string from beginning to end where split the string by `_` where each new string much match of of the predefined rule such as:

input string should start with att|ptt which end with between 1-6; then next new word either epic or semi; then it should be app or app1~app6 or app{1_6}*clm{1~6}*{sub|sup_}; then string end with {valid|invalid};

how should I specify those rules by using re.compile to check pattern in input string and raise error if it is not sequentially? How should we do this in python? any quick way of making this happen?

Comment: This is a character class `[att]` matching either `a` or `t` Why do you have to split instead of writing a single pattern to validate the whole string?

Comment: Perhaps you can use something like this `^[ap]tt[0-6]_(?:epic|semi)_app[0-6]?(?:_clm[0-9]*_su[bp])?_valid$` https://regex101.com/r/RF04Ni/1

Comment: You don't have to use split, you can add an alternation with another option like https://regex101.com/r/VZWuWO/1

Comment: The pattern does not match  `att12`, you can see the example in the answer I have added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248180/discussion-between-beyond-inifinity-and-the-fourth-bird).

Comment: @Thefourthbird can I clarify one doubt from you if possible? I sent my question to chat. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using split, you could consider writing a pattern that validates the whole string.

If I am reading the requirements, you might use:

```
^[ap]tt[0-6]_(?:epic|semi)_app(?:[1-6]|[1-6_]clm[0-9]*_su[bp])?_valid$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[ap]tt[0-6]` match `att` or `ptt` and a digit 0-6
- `_(?:epic|semi)` Match `_epic` or `_semi`
- `_app` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `[1-6]` Match a digit 1-6
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-6_]clm[0-9]*_su[bp]` Match a digit 1-6 or `_`, then `clm` followed by optional digit 0-9 and then `_sub` or `_sup`
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `_valid` Match literally
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ONYIBM/1).

If the string can also start with dev then you can use an alternation:

```
^(?:[ap]tt|dev)[0-6]_(?:epic|semi)_app(?:[1-6]|[1-6_]clm[0-9]*_su[bp])?_valid$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VZWuWO/1).

Then you can check if there was a match:

```
import re

pattern = r"^(?:[ap]tt|dev)[0-6]_(?:epic|semi)_app(?:[1-6]|[1-6_]clm[0-9]*_su[bp])?_valid$"

strings = [
    "att2_epic_app_clm1_sub_valid",
    "att12_epic_app_clm1_sub_valid",
    "att2_epic_app_valid",
    "att2_epic_app_clm1_sub_valid"
]

for s in strings:
    m = re.match(pattern, s, re.M)
    if m:
        print("Valid: " + m.group())
    else:
        print("Invalid: " + s)
```

Output

```
Valid: att2_epic_app_clm1_sub_valid
Invalid: att12_epic_app_clm1_sub_valid
Valid: att2_epic_app_valid
Valid: att2_epic_app_clm1_sub_valid
```